# Probability of a combination

Tags: probability, statistics

If you have 6 red marbles and 6 blue marbles and 1 white marble, what is the probability of any combination granted it has always has a white marble in a combination of 6 random drawn marble?

If you can explain the math I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Am I interpreting your questions correctly:

Let's say you have 6 red, 6, blue, and 1 white marble in a bag.  You draw 6 randomly (w/o replacement) and one of them is white.  What is the probability of getting: (5 red 1 white), (4 red 1 blue 1 white), ..., (5 blue 1 white)?

Comment: Yes that is correct! One must always be white.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve the problem. Imagine the $13$  balls to be arranged in some randomly chosen order. The probability the white is among the first $6$ is $\frac{6}{13}$.

**Another way:** Imagine the balls are all distinct. Then there are $\binom{13}{6}$ equally likely ways to choose $6$ balls from the $13$.

There are $\binom{1}{1}\binom{12}{5}$ ways to choose $1$ white and $5$ non-white. Thus our required probability is $\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{12}{5}}{\binom{13}{6}}$. This simplifies to $\frac{6}{13}$.

**Another way:** The probability that the $6$ balls are **non-white** is $\frac{12}{13}\cdot\frac{11}{12}\cdot\frac{10}{11}\cdots\frac{7}{8}$. This simplifies to $\frac{7}{13}$.

Comment: This may seem a bit off and thank you for the answer but how many different combinations are there? I forgot to ask that part too.

Comment: It depends what you mean by combinations. Are balls of the same colour to be considered "the same" or not? If "the same" and we are counting combinations with $1$ white, the number of red can be any of $0$ to $5$, so $6$ choices.

Comment: Sorry, How many different combinations of 6 marbles can there be if you limit the number to sets with just a white marble. Like timidpueo put in the comment if I were to count all the combinations as "(5 red 1 white), (4 red 1 blue 1 white), ..., (5 blue 1 white)" how many would I have. Sorry I am being a pain you're a great help.

Comment: I answered that in the comment above, there are $6$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think he wants them broken out into cases, ie What is the probability of getting 5R 1W? What is the probability of getting 4R 1B 1W?  What is the probability of getting 3R 2R 1W? etc...

Comment: It is reasonable to suppose that OP wants these various probabilities. However, the original problem can be solved (in several ways) without calculating probabilities of the various colour combinations, and nowhere is there an explicit request for the probability of say $1$ white $2$ red $3$ blue. But for the record it is $\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{3}$ divided by $\binom{13}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution): $\frac{\binom11\binom{12}5}{\binom{12}6}$ is the right answer.